# There are pawns at each of two ending cells of 1 × 20 strip

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving, computational-mathematics

There are pawns at each of two ending cells of 1 × 20 strip. In a single step a player can shift one of the pawns towards the second one by one or two cells. It is forbidden to jump over a pawn. The player who cannot make a step loses the game. Who has a winning strategy - the player who starts the game or his opponent?

Comment: The standard first approach with these games is to start from an end position, say who has lost (in this case the player whose turn it is) then work your way back one square at a time, always asking "can the current player force their opponent into a losing position?" Try that, see what you can find. (Also note that in this game, it doesn't matter where on the strip the pawns are, only how many squares are between them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game is equivalent to a simple takeaway game. The game starts with a pile of $18$ stones. Each player in turn must take either one or two stones from the pile; the player who takes the last stone wins, since the other player cannot make a move.

Observe that if there are $3$ stones left, the player whose turn it is must lose: no matter what that player does, the other player can always take the last stone. Thus, if you can leave your opponent $3$ stones, you’ll win. If you leave your opponent $4$ or $5$ stones, however, your opponent can leave you $3$ stones and win. What if you leave your opponent $6$ stones? $9$ stones?

Comment: The game starts with a pile of $18$ stones, not $20$.

Comment: @TonyK: You’re absolutely right; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The losing positions for the player to move are those in which the number of empty squares between the pawns is a multiple of $3$. So the second player wins.